# React - Children Accessing Parents state too early?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

When using a callback from a child to app.js, the callback function in app.js sets the state for an element.
In the same child-function, on the next line, the function accesses this state, which is passed along as a prop.
Is there a way to make sure that this next line executes with the updated state already? If not, whats a better way to implement this?

Child Component

```
function handleCountrySelected(selected) {
    let selectedValues = {
      countries: selected,
      planningGroups: null,
    };


    onFilterChange(selectedValues); // changes selectedFilters.country via callback

    console.log(selectedFilters.countries); // still old state. selectedFilters is a prop from apps.state. Here it is still showing the old value
    filters_changed();
    autoApply && applyFilter(); // applyFilter fails because its accessing old state, still.
}
```

App.js

```
updateSelectedFilters(selectedValues) {
    this.setState({
      selectedFilters: {
        ...this.state.selectedFilters,
        ...selectedValues
      }
    }

...

<NavbarTopFilters onApplyFilters={this.onApplyFilters}
                              selectedFilters={this.state.selectedFilters}
                              onFilterChange={this.updateSelectedFilters}
/>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`setState` is an async function. You need to pass in the rest of the lines as a callback.

```
function updateSelectedFilters(selectedValues, callback) {
    this.setState({selectedFilters: {...}}, callback);
    ...
}

onFilterChange(selectedValues, () => { console.log(...) });
```